# Advice needed to parse this JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Given the following JSON samples, what is the best way to parse this in c# .NET?

```
{"data":{"5":{"isDeleted":"false","day":"THU"}},"action":"edit"}
{"data":{"7":{"isDeleted":"false","name":"alex"}},"action":"edit"}
{"data":{"90":{"isDeleted":"true","job":"software"}},"action":"edit"}
```

I have looked into JSON serializing into an object but because the data could be different each time i can't map it directly to a model.

Comment: What do you want to do, and how different are the fields? You could deserialize it into a JsonDocument and work with JSON elements directly. If you know the possible field names in advance you can add all of them as nullable fields, eg `string?` or `bool?`. Or you could use a `Dictionary<string,whatever>` to represent truly dynamic items

Comment: It would help to know what JSON parsing library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the model for this could be

```
public class Record 
{
  public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Data { get; set; }
  public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the JSON into a `dynamic` object, which allows you to access the properties of the JSON object without having to define a specific model with `JsonSerializer` of `System.Text.Json`:

```
string jsonString = "{\"data\":{\"5\":{\"isDeleted\":\"false\",\"day\":\"THU\"}},\"action\":\"edit\"}";
dynamic jObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString);
string action = jObject .action;
dynamic data = jObject .data;
string isDeleted = data["5"].isDeleted;
string day = data["5"].day;
```